# Retrieving contract abstraction multiple times?

Tags: contract-invocation

In the Metacoin sample provided with Truffle webpack I see that in app.js the contract abstraction is retrieved in multiple functions using the .deployed() function.  Is there a reason I couldn't just get it once when the script starts and store it?  Why do we need to get it multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call ".deployed()" several times, that's probably just a simplification on the sample code. It is no problem to save and reuse the abstraction.